# How to round a floating point type to two decimals or more in C++?

Tags: c++, floating-point, c++17

How can I round a float to two decimals points or more in C++17? I'm not looking to print/output the rounded float, but to actually change the value. Also, what's the most efficient method if I'm constantly iterating through a loop and rounding floats?

Comment: So is this the most efficient method? `float nearest = roundf(val * 100) / 100;  /* Result: 37.78 */` Also, if I want to get three decimal points do I just change the 100 to 1000?

Comment: It seems to be the most efficient method, although I'm sure other similar methods exist.

Comment: It isn't the most efficient method because it isn't even a method. It doesn't work in 90% of cases. Floating-point values don't have decimal places, they have binary places. and the two are incommensurable, so what you ask is impossible, unless you go ntoa  decial radix. @JackBashford

Comment: Would it be better to just leave floats as they are rather than rounding them if I'm only using them for calculations?